# Jena & RDFS: Get property from external ontology

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, rdfs

I have an RDFS ontology with a `User` class as such:

```xml
<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="User"> 
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent" />
    <rdfs:comment> 
        The class of users, subclassing the foaf:Agent class.
    </rdfs:comment>  
</rdfs:Class>
```

The `foaf:Agent` class has a property called `name`, which I would like to load using Jena with something similar to:

```
Property name = model.getOntProperty(ns + "name");
```

The problem is that I get a NullPointerException when I try to use it like this:

```
model.createStatement(resource, name, "Nicolas Cage");
```

I have tried with the foaf standard namespace as well (`ns = "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/";`), even though I am not sure how much sense that makes.

In the end, I have no idea what the right approach for this is. Should I create it? Doesn't Jena somehow find it automatically in the external ontology?

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example. Details matter.  
Your null pointer is due to something different - check the stacktrace.

Comment: You don't have to load anything in order to create a property.  Properties are identified by URIs, and you simply need to reference the URI, which you're doing correctly with `Property name = model.getOntProperty(ns + "name");` if, in fact, `ns` is `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RDF, resources, including properties, are *identified* by URIs.  There's no sense in which you need to *load* those URIs.  Sometimes documents that are identified by URIs might contain statements that you want, in which case, you'd need to load a document containing those, but that's different than simply referencing the property.  Here's an example:

```java
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFFormat;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;

public class UseFoafNameExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Property name = model.createProperty( "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name" );
        Resource resource = model.createResource( "http://stackoverflow.com/q/23818390/1281433/NicholasCage" );
        Statement s = model.createStatement( resource, name, "Nicholas Cage" );
        model.add( s );
        RDFDataMgr.write( System.out, model, RDFFormat.RDFXML_ABBREV );
    }
}
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23818390/1281433/NicholasCage">
    <j.0:name>Nicholas Cage</j.0:name>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now, there's another problem in your question.

> The foaf:Agent class has a property called name, which I would like to
>   load using Jena with something similar to:

the foaf:Agent class doesn't have a property;  that's not how RDFS (and OWL) classes work.  There's a property `name` that has `Agent` as an `rdfs:domain` (I didn't check that this is actually the case, but it sounds reasonable, and I'm guessing that that's where the confusion arose from).  That means that when you have a triple

```
x foaf:name "some name"
```

you can *infer* that

```
x rdf:type foaf:Agent
```

Of course, to do that sort of inference, you need to know about the triple

```
foaf:name rdfs:domain foaf:Agent
```

and *that's* what you may want to load an ontology from someplace else.  I.e., you want to get the *axioms* that it contains, so that you can reason with them.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in RDF you don't necessarily have to define a resource as `foaf:Agent` if you just create it and link it to the `foaf:name` property?

Comment: If you assert that `x foaf:name "foo"` *and* you have the triple `foaf:name rdfs:domain foaf:Agent` *and* you have a reasoner, then you can *infer* that `x rdf:type foaf:Agent`.

Answer (score 0):

Jena will not automatically load something just because it is mentioned.

```
rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent"
```

is just a mention of the name Agent and say nothing about fetching it.  Its just any old URI to RDF - and it may not exist.